# Redshift not logging to STL_WLM_RULE_ACTION

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift cluster associated with a parameter group that monitors queries via workload management (WLM). I have rules that perform the "log" action whenever the number of rows scanned crosses a threshold (e.g. 100).

However, when I execute the SQL queries that satisfy the rule and then check the `STL_WLM_RULE_ACTION` table, where the query is supposed to be logged, the table comes up empty. Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Are you connecting as a Superuser? Only superusers can see all the data in STL_WLM_RULE_ACTION, other users will only see rows for their own queries. If you are executing a query as one user then checking STL_WLM_RULE_ACTION while connected as another (non super-) user you will potentially not see any rows.

Comment: I am connecting as a superuser and I'm executing the query and checking the table as the same user.

Answer (score 1):

Nathan's answer (about data visibility in `STL_WLM_RULE_ACTION`) is a good one.

You should **also** double check that your Parameter Group has been applied:

- In the AWS Redshift Console, select the your cluster on `Clusters` page
- On the `Configuration` tab, under `Cluster Properties`, is `Cluster Parameter Group` set to the correct group?

  - *You can click on parameter group name to go to it and confirm.*

If the parameter group you wanted has not been applied then:

- On the `Configuration` tab, click the `Cluster` drop down and choose `Modify`.
- Use the `Cluster Parameter Group` to select the correct group.
- *Carefully review the other options to avoid unintended changes.*
- Click `Modify` to apply the new parameter group.
- If `Parameter Group Apply Status` says "Reboot required" then click the `Cluster` drop down and choose `Reboot`.

Comment: Yes, I've applied the correct parameter group, but I'm getting the issue anyway.

Comment: @charmander There will only be entries when the query was affected by a WLM Rule in some way. Are you getting, for instance, a "query aborted" message and _then_ finding that there is nothing in this table?

Comment: For now I've only set the query actions to log the query if a certain threshold is crossed. I've run queries against it that cross that threshold, yet nothing is being logged.